# Video compressed using ffmpeg-android-java library, does not play on Web browsers

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg

I am capturing video using default camera in Android and compressing it using [ffmpeg-android-java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library.

After successful compression, video is playing in MXPlayer app, but fails to play in Web browsers like Google Chrome, Firefox.

What can be the reason?

I have shared my compression logic. What changes can I make here so it can play on browsers?

```
String[] str=new String[]{"-y" ,"-i",sourceFilename,"-strict","experimental","-s", "160x120","-r","25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b", "150k", "-ab","48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", destinationFilename};

try{
            FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getActivity());
            ffmpeg.execute(str, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {}

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String message) {
                    Log.e("onProgress",message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.e("onFailure",message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.e("onSuccess",message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {}
            });
        }  catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vcodec should be `libx264`. The browsers, likely, can't play MPEG-4 Part 2. You should add `"-movflags","+faststart"` for quick start of playback.